# can't ping the same IP twice

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, ping

I have written this code for pinging class C IP addresses on port 6789, the thread starts when I click on a button called `PING`. It will retrieve all IP addresses that has the port 6789 open. But what I need is to refresh (re-ping) every, let's say 5 seconds, and add IPs recently joined if exist and omit ones that leave the port. Unfortunately another issue appears. When I started the application the first iteration of the `while (true)` works perfectly, and it adds any IP that had the port 6789 open to the `ArrayList ips_List` and then display it on the `ListView`, and when another device joins the port, my phone will add it to the `ips_List` also. BUT in the second iteration after the Thread sleeps 5 seconds and then begins to re-ping the IPs from (x.x.x.1 - x.x.x.254) to see if another IP had joined the port when pinging to an IP previously pinged, the Socket will throw IOException (as written in the code).

Why is that happening?

```
Thread pingo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {

                    if (readableNetmask.equals("255.255.255.0")) {

                        for (int i = 2; i <= 25; i++) {

                            String ip_address = readableIPAddress;
                            String oct1 = "", oct2 = "", oct3 = "", oct4 = "";

                            StringTokenizer stok = new StringTokenizer(
                                    ip_address, ".");

                            while (stok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                                oct1 = stok.nextToken();
                                oct2 = stok.nextToken();
                                oct3 = stok.nextToken();
                                oct4 = stok.nextToken();
                            }

                            to_ping_ip = oct1 + "." + oct2 + "." + oct3
                                    + "." + String.valueOf(i);

                            if (pingAddress(to_ping_ip, 6789)) {
                                ips_List.add(to_ping_ip);
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    // delay 10 seconds, then re-ping
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                    handler.post(new UpdateIPListViewRunnable());
                }
            }
        });
        pingo.start();
```

PingAddress() function:

```
public boolean pingAddress(String ip, int port) {

   Socket socket = new Socket();
   try {

      socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), 200);
      socket.close();

   } catch (IOException e) {
       return false;
   }
   return true;
   }
```

List where addresses appear:

```
static public class UpdateIPListViewRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < ips_List.size(); i++) {
            arrayAdapter.add(ips_List.get(i));
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        ips_List.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ask a complete, self-contained question.

Comment: it's from the previous question [Ping every 5 seconds]; 
When pinging a specific IP it suscceeds but when the thread enters the seconds loop after the Sleeping 5 seconds ... the ping failed when pinging an IP that has previously pinged and has the port 6789 opened.. I don't know why ???

Comment: Please ask a complete, self-contained question? That means the question must stand on its own. Include your code, a problem statement, etc.

Comment: sorry for that, I edited the question ...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely in your atypical usage of the word "ping".  Traditionally, this refers to sending an ICMP echo request, which does not involve connection state, but is also often not allowed to ordinary user IDs such as your application will run under.

You appear to be using a stateful TCP connection instead, and may be running into difficulty in if your server is not tuned to be able to accept rapid reconnects.  So you may want to try testing your server using some other client.  You could also have a problem in that TCP will keep trying to get the traffic through, so it won't quickly report network troubles.  You may even be ending up with multiple attempts overlapping in time.

Your best solution though would probably be to switch from TCP, which is ill suited to this task, to UDP, which is probably a better match.  UDP does not have connection state, and it's also *unreliable* in that no automatic retries are attempted.  You should be able to find a UDB echo server and client type example with a web search.

Comment: Thank you @Chris Stratton ... and there is noway that I am changing to protocol to UDP since my project's structure is build over the TCP architecture ... now for my problem I finally FOUND the solution;

Comment: Its not clear what fix you think you found, but beware that the precise behavior resulting from misusing TCP may not be reliable across installations, networks, and time.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, I write down the solution below in my answer, it is working perfectly and doesn't display any errors in the `Logcat`.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour, please can you clarify more about how I may be misusing TCP ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Chris Stratton ... and there is noway that I am changing to protocol to UDP since my project's structure is build over the TCP architecture ... now for my problem I finally FOUND the solution; in my app i have a `ServerSocket` that is used for pinging ... now considering there are two mobiles with the same app, if PING button clicked then it will ping the other device and and the other device will `accept()` the connection then `close()` it. Now on the first mobile it will iterates another time (`while(true)`) and ping the same device, but that device has the `ServerSocket` closed so it will returns `false`. For this is used a recursive thread that when a mobile 1 pings mobile 2, mobile 2 will close the `ServerSocket` and immediately calls the same thread so the `ServerSocket` is opened to other pings. I tried it and it worked very well :DDD

[@Experts: any enhancements for this solution!]

Recursive Thread:

```
static public class ReceivePingThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket joinPort = new ServerSocket(6789, 100);
            joinPort.accept();
            joinPort.close();
            ReceivePingThread ReceivePingThread = new ReceivePingThread();
            ReceivePingThread.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may sort of work, in some cases, but it's actually doing a lot of things behind the scenes in the TCP stack which aren't usually desired in a simple "ping" type of test.  In particular, closing down a TCP connection can be a fairly lengthy process, and often is only completed by a timeout.  Without the right flags on the connection, you may not be able to connect again until the old one times out.  And if you have a lot of clients doing this rapidly, you can bring the system down from the weight of incompletely closed connections waiting out the timeout, unless you configure a limit.

Comment: However, webservers necessarily face the same problem (and yes, people sometimes 'ping' web servers with actual TCP connections and send  HTTP requests through them), so while TCP remains "the wrong tool for the ping job"  the difficulties *can* be overcome with sufficient care.  And where possible, modern HTTP prefers to keep connections alive rather than opening a new one for every single request.